# Is it possible to have local git repositories in artifactory?

Tags: git, version-control, repository, local, artifactory

Project will be hosted on premises without connection to public internet.
Is it possible to upload git repository in artifactory?

If so, how could I achieve that? Tried to research but what I find that I can only cache repositories from github/ bitbucket... when creating remote vcs ? But this doesn't allow to upload git repo as artefact?

Comment: [git bundle](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle) is how Git operates over sneakernet.

Comment: Why do you want the git repository in Artifactory? Why not use a git server like gitlab or bitbucket?

Comment: I was thinking maybe its possible to have all repositories managed by one software. 
But was looking more into gitea project.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `git archive` to create a `tar.gz` which contains the content of a given commit, and upload that to artifactory.

Comment: Yeah, I can archive it. But how to upload it to artifactory? What repository should I create: vcs / git lcs / generic? 

I tried to upload it on git lcs repository. But I am not able to use  "git clone localRepoUrl".

And on remote vcs I am not able to upload artefact myself... :/

Comment: Where is the artifactory instance located (internet ? on prem ?) ? how can the system that is cut from the internet access this artifactory instance ?

Comment: Instance and the app will be located in the same closed private network (on premises).

Comment: Ok. The hoster can't be accessed from outside ; how can the artifactory be accessed ? Is it also unreachable from the internet ?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/package-bundle this plugin allows to download every package needed. Thus you have zip which can then be uploaded to artifactory as artefact :)